# How can I instruct Google Talk to remain in the taskbar when closed?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, notification-area, google-talk

This seems like a silly question, but does anyone know how I can instruct Google Talk to remain 'open' in my taskbar when closed ( much like skype can be configured to do ); or to restore the 'already-running' instance in the tray?

I've observed that with an instance running in the tray, I can't simply click on a 'pinned' link on my taskbar, but rather I have to work my way over to the tray and double click the GT icon. An annoyance, at most, but something that I feel should be integrated in some way, and I'm hoping someone knows how to enable such a feature, or hack around the lack there-of.

While typing all of this, it crossed my mind that I could write an application that emulates clicking the GT icon in the tray... but that seems a little excessive.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, Google Talk was not designed that way.  It was explicitly designed to sit in your systray.

So I'm afraid it is not possible without something like you suggested in your last paragraph...

Comment: Fair answer. Thanks, I'll look into it and consider a release ;)